# SQL Server Pivot all Table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I'd like to pivot my table by all of its columns
Original table e.g

| Report Date | TotalOrders | TotalValueOrders | OrderItem1 | OrderItem2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | 5 | 25 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-01-12 | 7 | 50 | 5 | 2 |
| 2021-01-13 | 10 | 65 | 5 | 5 |

To the following:

| Header | 2021-01-11 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TotalOrders | 5 | 7 | 10 |
| TotalValueOrders | 25 | 50 | 65 |
| OrderItem1 | 3 | 5 | 5 |
| OrderItem2 | 2 | 2 | 5 |

This is what I have done so far but I'm not sure this is the most efficient way of doing this to be honest any other suggestions would be welcome -
(1) also how would I go about getting the rows into an appropriate sort order that I need and
(2) also what to do if a new row of data is inserted with a new date for dynamic date column names

```
create table #Results(
ReportDate dateTime
,TotalOrders nvarchar(10)
,TotalValueOrders Nvarchar(10)
,OrderItem1 nvarchar(10)
,OrderItem2 nvarchar(10)
)

insert #Results
values('2021-01-11','5','25','3','2')
,('2021-01-12','7','50','5','2')
,('2021-01-13','10','65','5','5')

--select * from #Results

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 'TotalValueOrders' as Header, ReportDate ,TotalValueOrders
 FROM #Results SOH 
    
) AS Sales 
PIVOT (max(TotalValueOrders)
FOR ReportDate IN ([2021-01-11 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-12 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-13 00:00:00.000]))
as PVT
union
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 'OrderItem1' as Header,ReportDate ,OrderItem1
 FROM #Results SOH 
    
) AS Sales 
PIVOT (max(OrderItem1)
FOR ReportDate IN ([2021-01-11 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-12 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-13 00:00:00.000]))
as PVT
union
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 'OrderItem2' as Header, ReportDate ,OrderItem2
 FROM #Results SOH 
    
) AS Sales 
PIVOT (max(OrderItem2)
FOR ReportDate IN ([2021-01-11 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-12 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-13 00:00:00.000]))
as PVT
union
SELECT  * FROM 
(
SELECT 'TotalOrders' as Header ,ReportDate ,TotalOrders --,TotalValueOrders,OrderItem1,OrderItem2
 FROM #Results SOH 
    
) AS Sales 
PIVOT (max(TotalOrders)
FOR ReportDate IN ([2021-01-11 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-12 00:00:00.000],[2021-01-13 00:00:00.000])) 
as PVT
```

Comment: It isn't the most efficient no. What you really need to do is unpivot your data, and then pivot it. I'd, personally, also suggest using a `VALUES` table construct for the unpivot, and conditional aggregation for the pivot, rather than the more restrictive `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` operators. Of course, all these solutions will be static; they won't change the columns returned when you get  more values for `ReportDate`. If you need a dynamic solution, I suggest rethinking about your decisions to do this in SQL. A matrix in SSRS, or a pivot table in Excel would be far better options for that.

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic and add new dates you would need to create dynamic SQL to create the query for you.  

Is there a reason you want to do this in SQL rather than in a consuming application like SSRS, Excel, ETC?